# Graph of a function is real plane.

Tags: real-analysis

What is the graph of f(X)=X^2 , when X is rational
                                            =0 ,when X is irrational
Is the function is no where differential except 0.?

Answer (score 0):

The function is not continuos if $x \ne 0$, so it is not differentiable if $x \ne 0$

Let's see what happens in zero

$\lim_{h \to 0}(\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}) = \lim_{h \to 0}(\frac{h^{2}}{h}) = 0$ if $h$ is a rational number

And $\lim_{h \to 0}(\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}) = \lim_{h \to 0}(\frac{0}{h}) = 0$ if $h$ is a irrational number

Then $f$ is differentiable in $x = 0$, and $f'(0) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

It is well-known that $f$ is not continuous at any $x \neq 0$, so a fortiori it cannot be differentiable at any $x\neq 0$.

At $x=0$, let $h$ be some number $\neq 0$, then we have the study the differential quotient $\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h-0}=\frac{f(h)}{h}$.

For $h$ irrational we have that $f(h) = 0$ and so the expresssion $\frac{f(h)}{h} $ is $0$ for all $h$ irrational.

For $H$ rational, we have that $f(h) = h^2$ and so $\frac{f(h)}{h} = \frac{h^2}{h}= h$ for all $h$ rational.

Now, if $\varepsilon >0$ we just pick $\delta = \varepsilon$ and if then $h \in (-\delta, \delta)\setminus \{0\}$ then regardless of $h$ being rational or irrational, the above considerations tell us that $| \frac{f(h)}{h} - 0| < \varepsilon$.

So by the definition of limit, $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)- 0}{h-0} = 0$$

and so $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ with $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: I want see the graph... If any.

Comment: @SubhasishChowdhury you cannot really draw the graph. It’s like a parabola in the rationals with lots of points in the $x$-axis in between.